# Testing GET in a rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a feeling I'm just doing something wrong syntactically but it's surprisingly difficult to Google "GET" so I was hoping someone here might know the answer to this.

I'm trying to test a Rails controller from an RSpec test. I'm following an example I found here - http://www.elevatedrails.com/articles/2007/09/10/testing-controllers-with-rspec/ but I'm stuck on the actual execution of the method I'm testing.

I'm doing a GET request where as the post above does a POST. I'm passing in 2 parameters manufacturer and model.

My URL will ideally look something like http://mysite.com/Products/index/Manufacturer/ModelName

I can't figure out the syntax for the get request call in the rest. Right now I have

```
get :index, :manufacturer=>@manufacturer, :modelName=>@modelName
```

and I get back

> ArgumentError in 'ProductController Find a valid product should retrieve the product'
>   wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)

Any thoughts?

edit: It should be noted @manufacturer and @modelName are defined in before(:each)

Comment: The syntax is fine.  Something else is wonky.  Post more details!  Post a few more lines of your error backtrace, post your whole failing spec, post the relevant part of your controller, and post the relevant routes.  :)

Comment: Also as a note, it looks like you're disobeying a few Rails conventions, which might make your life harder rather than easier.  modelName should be model_name and ProductController should probably be ProductsController plural.

Comment: Also you should probably lose the capitals in the url, also why would you nest a list of manufacturers of an index for products. Surely that would work better /products/manufacturers, and as this would be a many to many have you ruled out /manufacturers/products as well?

But as mentioned code is needed to get to the bottom of your problem.

Comment: I found the answer which ill post below but just wanted to respond to the comments. 

Conventions wise ya, im a bit new to rails. I'm a PHP/.NET dev mainly so just trying to catch on. Thanks for pointing that out i will change that. 

Regarding the nesting the goal is to ultimately locate a single product with both parameters. The url will be site.com/manufacturer/model_name. Maybe it would be better to put in the manufacturers controller but product seemed logical as im trying to find a product not the manufacturer of the product. I might be thinking about it wrong though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i suspected this was me being green to rails programming.

I was defining the controller method as

```
def index(manufacturer, modelName)
```

When really i needed to use the params hash to access the attributes. I then had to define a custom route as id is the only parameter expected to be passed into a controller method by default.

once i did that i changed the spec to read

```
get :index, {:manufacturer=>@manufacturer, :modelName=>@modelName}
```

and it worked.

Thanks for the comments everyone.